# Array coverting to float and double

Tags: java

Please help.

Can you give me example of this question?:

> Write a program that creates an array of integers (size of 10), then
> convert them individually to float and double data types as you print
> them out.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site where you have to show what have you tried, and not just ask people to do the things for you. You can post your queries here, but not something that you haven't even tried!

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[10] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};

//converting to double and printing them individually

for(int i : array){
double d = i;

System.out.println("Double :" + d);


}



//converting to float and printing them individually

for(int i : array){
float d = i;

System.out.println("Float :" + d);


}
```